# Go templates - Search all keys recursively

Tags: docker, go, go-templates

I often find myself in need to find a specific key in **docker x** command output. I usually use **grep** sometimes **jq** command but maybe go templates have some build mechanism to output a key and it's value without knowing the specific "path" of that value ?

For example in case of `docker image inspect <x>` command the path to Cmd would be something like **[0].ContainerConfig.Cmd** or **[0].Config.Cmd**

is it possible to retrieve both of those keys and their values in Go template ?

Comment: you probably want to look at https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client

Comment: Might need a better example. Can you point to some images where ContainerConfig.Cmd is defined but Config.Cmd is not?

Answer (score 2):

Only awkwardly.  Split on to multiple lines, you could write

```
{{- if .ContainerConfig.Cmd -}}
{{- .ContainerConfig.Cmd -}}
{{- else if .Config.Cmd -}}
{{- .Config.Cmd -}}
{{- else -}}
""
{{- end -}}
```

You'd have to remove the newlines and pack that into a single `docker inspect -f` option, which is inconvenient.

Using `jq` as you suggest in the question is probably a little easier; or @Vorsprung's suggestion of using a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) will let you do this in code in a language richer than the bare Go `text/template` language.